# Why parallax background image is resizing on scroll? (Via devtools)

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome-devtools, performance-testing, parallax

I have created parallax site using stellar.js. But it turned out a bit laggy/janky . So i jumped in, to debug this. All day i'm watching all kinds of videos about speeding up websites performance, i discovered more about chrome devtools, especially Timeline tab . Things got better, but still, in timeline most costly thing is painting. That happens because images are resizing. **Question here is why bg-image are resizing on each scroll event?** In my mind browser renders images and resize them when i load page, not on each scroll. I know that position should be calculated on each scroll, but does it means that bowser also need to recalculate image size? If so, is there any fix to this? In some videos/articles i saw `transform: translateZ(0);` , but it's not helping in my case.
Here is code for each slide wrap. I know that `background-size:cover;` is costly, but thats the only way i can keep my full-screen backgrounds, they are large (2000x1200), but not heavy (350kb).

```
.slide{
background-attachment: fixed;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Would be thankful for any ideas. Or just discussion about this "painting" thing in general

Comment: Only on an intranet should a 350K background image be considered "not heavy".

Comment: for full-screen background image, i think its decent size. But ok , i get it :) not heavy, but medium size

Comment: We will need more to work with here.. Stellar.js is great, I tried it and found it annoying to work with. But it depends you may have a scroll event that shrinks your images.  If you have the time.. Write your own custom code, its not to difficult just takes a little extra time.

Comment: i like stellar, it's easy to work with. i used plugin because im not confident yet, probably i wouldn't make anything better. Writing my own code definitely will be next step. Im getting comfortable with jquery now.
if u are interested, here is available live version :) http://www.abstrakt.lv/abstrakt_dev/zimolu-un-grafiskais-dizains last slide is kinda janky, if u look at text

Comment: Consider removing footer, it's one of the biggest bottlenecks on your page. http://imgur.com/kUJ27lx - left part of the chart shows how page behaves while scrolling with footer, right part shows the same but with footer removed.